# Shuffling of colors

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a table with 2 rows and 7 columns.In 1st row each cell will be in different color.In 2nd row i have created a text box.Now i want my 1st row colors to get shuffled using jquery or javascript.i.e the colors should be placed in different cells.
here is my code for the table of colors

```
<div class="form-group" >
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd" style="color:#FFFFFF" > Color Password:</label>
<div class="col-sm-5">
<table  border="5px" width="300px" height="50px" align="center">
<tr>
<label><td bgcolor="blue" height="25px" ></td></label>
<label><td bgcolor="red" height="25px" ></td></label>

<label><td bgcolor="green" height="25px" ></td></label>
<label><td bgcolor="yellow" height="25px" ></td></label>

<label><td bgcolor="orange" height="25px" ></td></label>
<label><td bgcolor="black" height="25px" ></td></label>

<label><td bgcolor="pink" height="25px"></td></label>
<label><td bgcolor="brown" height="25px"></td></label>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="text" size="4" name="blue"></td>
<td> <input type="text" size="4" name="red"></td>
<td> <input type="text" size="4" name="green"></td>
<td> <input type="text" size="4" name="yellow"></td>
<td> <input type="text" size="4" name="orange"></td>
<td> <input type="text" size="4" name="pink"></td>
<td> <input type="text" size="4" name="brown"></td>

</tr>
</table>

</div></div>
```

This is my output: https://jsfiddle.net/xhoqhk8a/
Now i want all those colors to get shuffled.Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Where is your jquery or javascript?

Comment: I am not familiar with jquery.So i did'nt try any code with it.I want you'll to tell me,Is there a way to shuffle the colors in the case of my code and how???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could shuffe your Background-color like that (using jQuery)

```
var colorCells = $('#colors > td');
$.each(colorCells, function(idx){
  $(colorCells[idx]).css("background-color", '#'+Math.random().toString(16).slice(-6));
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xhoqhk8a/2/

Alternatively without jQuery:

```
var colorCells = document.getElementById('colors').getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i = 0; i < colorCells.length; i++){
    colorCells[i].style.backgroundColor = '#'+Math.random().toString(16).slice(-6);
}
```

If that is all your JavaScript Code you want to use I would recommend not to use the plain JavaScript Version.

**edit**:

if you only want to use a fixed set of colors:

```
var colorCells = document.getElementById('colors').getElementsByTagName('td');
var colors = ["blue","red","green","yellow","orange","pink","brown","black"];
for(var i = 0; i < colorCells.length; i++){
    colorCells[i].style.backgroundColor = colors.splice(Math.random() * (colors.length - 0) + 0,1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but if you look up to my output, i've used only 7 colors and i want only those 7 colors to get shuffled.Say for eg,if blue occupies the 1st cell,after shuffling it may occupy the 3rd position etc.

Comment: I have fixed my colors. they are blue,red,green,yellow,orange,pink,brown,black. And i want only these colors to get shuffled.

Comment: Look at my edited answer above, this should work just fine :) Note that the amount of colors you use have to be at least the amount of table cells.

Comment: No Problem, please consider marking my answer as correct :)

Comment: Can u tell me how to obtain the color name of each cell after shuffling @Patrick Rath